# How to get value in a dialog box to Mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Dialog Box is a jQuery Dialog Box, my popup use `<%Html.RenderPartial("MyUC")%>` to call a user control for Markup for a Dialog Box. How to the controller can call the value in Dialog Box?

---

**It's my dialog code**

```
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function() {
                    $("#edit").submit();
                    $('#dialog p').empty();
                }, 
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $('#dialog p').empty();                        
                }
            },                
            close: function() {
                allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');                   
            }
        });

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#dialog p').append('Click \'OK\' to confirm Edit of <b>$' + $("#Item").val());
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }

        $("input[name=Edit]").click(function() {

            var hd = $(this).next(); //will give u hidden div

            $("#dialog input[id=ItemId]").val(hd.children("#ItemId").val());
            //$("#dialog input[id=CatId]").val(hd.children("#CatId").val());
            $("#dialog select > option[id=" + hd.children("#CatId").val() + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#dialog input[id=UnitId]").val(hd.children("#UnitId").val());
            $("#dialog input[id=SaleOffId]").val(hd.children("#SaleOffId").val());
            $("#dialog input[id=ItemCode]").val(hd.children("#ItemCode").val());
            $("#dialog input[id=ItemName]").val(hd.children("#ItemName").val());
            $("#dialog input[id=UnitCost]").val(hd.children("#UnitCost").val());
            $("#dialog input[id=QuantityRemaining]").val(hd.children("#QuantityRemaining").val());
            $("#dialog form").attr("post", "/Item/EditTest/" + hd.children("#ItemId").val(),'json');

            alert("/Item/EditTest/" + hd.children("#ItemId").val());
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        })
    .hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        }
    ).mousedown(function() {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
    });
    });
```

---

And This is div contain dialog

```
  <% Html.BeginForm("EditTest", "Item"); %>
           <table>
             <tr>
               <td><b>ItemId</b></td>
               <td><input id="ItemId" name="ItemId" type="text" disabled="disabled" /></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>CatId</b></td>
               <td><input id="CatId" name="CatId" type="text" />
                   <%--<%= Html.DropDownList("CatId", ViewData["AllCategory"] as SelectList)%>--%></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>SaleOffId</b></td>
               <td><input id="SaleOffId" name="SaleOffId" type="text"/></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>UnitId</b></td>
               <td><input id="UnitId" name="UnitId" type="text" /></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>ItemCode</b></td>
               <td><input id="ItemCode" name="ItemCode" type="text" /></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>ItemName</b></td>
               <td><input id="ItemName" name="ItemName" type="text" /></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>UnitCost</b></td>
               <td><input id="UnitCost" name="UnitCost" type="text"/></td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><b>QuantityRemaining</b></td>
               <td><input id="QuantityRemaining" name="QuantityRemaining" type="text"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><input type="submit" id="Save" name="Save" value="Save" /></td>
               <td><input type="submit" id="Cancel" name="Cancel" value="Cancle" onclick="back(-1);" /></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
```

Comment: What do you meant by "can call the value"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vaule in a TextBox for example there are 2 ways for you to return valuse from the page.

In the Controller request the value specifically.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public SomeViewController(string stringValueFromTextBoxOnPartialView){}
```

The other way to do it is to request the whole form as a FormCollection. This was you can add a fiew input types to your page and you'll only need one object in you're controller.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public SomeViewController(FormCollection form){}
```

More detailed descriptions can be found at http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-33-cs.aspx

Comment: Sorry please help me understand your problem better. You have a form in a jQuery Dialog box that you want to post data back to a controller? Do you want the page to post back to happen asynchronously using Ajax or synchronously using browser postback? If you want to use Ajax then check out the docs at docs.jquery.com/Ajax and add the ajax code to this function in your code "Save": function() { } That will enable you to send the data to the controller and nicely close the DialogBox without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog must contain  element, which action url points to YorController/YourAction. Put some  with name attribute inside . Then submit the form when dialog "Ok" button is pressed - you'll have passed value in controller.

Answer (score 0):

If your dialog has a form field that wasn't there at the start, i.e. jQuery made it, the you can have your controller ask for it like this

```
this.Request["jQueryDialogElement"]
```

or

```
this.Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request["jQueryDialogElement"]
```

You can put a break point in and see if it is in the QueryString, or Form member of the Request object if you don't know.

Comment: If you aren't already, consider using Firefox and Firebug to find out more about what you jQuery is putting into your UI.